# bash: concatenating first value of multiple variables

Tags: arrays, bash, variables, concatenation

lets say i used grep and cut to store data into variables. i need to get the first second and third values of each variable concatenated with each other. i think i need to use arrays to achieve this but i don't know how to go about doing that. for example if $one holds a b c and $two holds 1 2 3 and $three holds x y z i want to concatenate so that my output would look like a1x b2y c3z. like i said i think i need to store my grep/cut output into an array but i am not sure how to do that. Thanks.

Comment: is this a homework assignment?

Comment: yes this is a homework assignment. i grep line of a file and cut certain characters out of the grep output.

Answer (score 1):

In pure bash, you can do something like this:

```
v1="a b c"
v2="1 2 3"
v3="x y z"
for v in v1 v2 v3; do
  read p1 p2 p3 <<< ${!v}
  a1="$a1$p1" 
  a2="$a2$p2" 
  a3="$a3$p3" 
done
echo $a1 
echo $a2 
echo $a3
```

The last three echoes output:

```
a1x
b2y
c3z
```

Comment: thanks. i got it to work with arrays though since i posted the question.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
v1="a b c"
v2="1 2 3"
v3="x y z"
parallel --xapply echo {1}{2}{3} ::: $v1 ::: $v2 ::: $v3
a1x
b2y
c3z
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed`,`tr`,etc to translate `' '` to `'\n'`.
Then use `paste` to concatenate them vertically.

```
$ v1="a b c"
$ v2="1 2 3"
$ v3="x y z"

$ paste <(tr ' ' '\n' <<<$v1) <(tr ' ' '\n' <<<$v2) <(tr ' ' '\n' <<<$v3) | tr -d '\t'
a1x
b2y
c3z
```

Or

```
$ paste <(echo "${v1// /$'\n'}") <(echo "${v2// /$'\n'}") <(echo "${v3// /$'\n'}") | tr -d '\t'
a1x
b2y
c3z
```

**Note:** If you save them in separated files, It will be much easier.

Comment: what do the 3 < symbols do after the \n?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution in pure bash using an array :

```
$ arr=( $v1 $v2 $v3 )

$ for ((i=0; i<3; i++)); do
    for ((j=i; j<${#arr[@]}; j+=3)); do printf '%s' ${arr[j]}; done
    echo
 done

a1x
b2y
c3z
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure bash using an array:

```
declare -a a=( $v1 $v2 $v3 )

echo "${a[0]}${a[3]}${a[6]}"
echo "${a[1]}${a[4]}${a[7]}"
echo "${a[2]}${a[5]}${a[8]}"
```